# dlopen Segmentation fault error when get a instance from shared library's exported function

Tags: c++, linux

I have been stuck in a problem for several days when using *dlopen/dlsym* to deal with the shared object. I desperately need your help!

There are three headers/source files： **Animal.h, Animal.cpp** and **test.cpp**, and two products: **libanimal.so** and **a.out**.

Here is the source code:

**Animal.h:**

```
// Animal.h
#ifndef STDLIB_ANIMAL_H
#define STDLIB_ANIMAL_H
#include <string>

class Animal {
public:
    Animal();
    std::string shout();
};

extern "C" Animal* createAnimal();

#endif //STDLIB_ANIMAL_H
```

**Animal.cpp**

```
// Animal.cpp
#include "Animal.h"

Animal::Animal() = default;

std::string Animal::shout() {
    return "WOW";
}

Animal* createAnimal() {
    return new Animal();
}
```

and the last one **test.cpp** which contained the main entry of the application:

```
// test.cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Animal.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    void *handle;
    // Open shared library
    handle = dlopen("./libanimal.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        /* fail to load the library */
        fprintf(stderr, "Handle Error: %s\n", dlerror());
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    auto spawnAnimal = reinterpret_cast<Animal* (*)()>(dlsym(handle, "createAnimal"));

    if (!spawnAnimal) {
        /* no such symbol */
        fprintf(stderr, "No Such Symbol Error: %s\n", dlerror());
        dlclose(handle);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    auto animal = spawnAnimal();
    std::cout << "call animal shout, the address of animal : " << animal <<std::endl;
    std::cout << animal->shout() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "after calling" << std::endl;
    dlclose(handle);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

First, I built **libanimal.so** shared library by the following command：

```sh
$ g++ -shared -fPIC -Wall -o libanimal.so Animal.cpp -std=c++0x
```

Then I built the executable, **a.out**:

```sh
$ g++ -Wall test.cpp -ldl -std=c++0x -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files
# --unresolved-symbols=ignore-all: tell linker to stop complaining about missing symbols
```

Both the above commands ran well without any error, but when I execute **a.out**, errors came out:

```sh
$ ./a.out
call animal shout, the address of animal : 0x7fffe97a4520
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I have searched lots of blogs/documentations, but all of them just post a really simple example:
The function they export always return like a std::string or char or int which is built-in type, not something like a object of a user-defined class, just like the showcase above (the **createAnimal** function).

So what's wrong with this? Could you please help me figuring out ?
Thank you !

BTW, my environment is:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: *The function they export always return like a std::string or char or int which is built-in type, not something like a object* -- A `std::string` is an object, no different than any object you would create.  So you should investigate why `std::string` works, but your object doesn't.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Than you ! I think the difference is obvious: the std::string class is provided by the standard c++ library.  But my custom class is implemented in my SO library, which is exotic.

Comment: That is not an "obvious difference".  The `std::string` is not magic.  It consists of ordinary C++ code -- it is not a "built-in" class or function, but a class that is properly made available, which you need to figure out.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I agree with you. The class itself doesn‘t have difference with std::string. But what I want to emphasise is that the example Animal class's implemention is imported from a shared library which is opened by dlopen, while std::string doesn't .

Comment: When you are calling `animal->shout()` what is actually called? My guess is that it tries to call something like `_ZN6Animal5shoutB5cxx11Ev` (see: name mangling) which you haven't loaded and your main binary does not contain it either as you told it to ignore missing symbols. It might be interesting to see it in the debugger what the crash actually is. BTW your example does not run for me, it prints: `error while loading shared libraries: unexpected PLT reloc type 0x00`. So I can't try this in the debugger for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my suspicion from the comment has confirmed itself. The problem is with the early binding on `animal->shout()` which resolves at compile time to a call to `_ZN6Animal5shoutB5cxx11Ev` and this symbol is nowhere to be found.

If I change it to virtual (late binding, resolved at runtime through a vtable):

```
// Animal.h
#ifndef STDLIB_ANIMAL_H
#define STDLIB_ANIMAL_H
#include <string>

class Animal {
public:
    Animal();
    virtual std::string shout();
    virtual ~Animal() {} // always put a virtual destructor if you have any virtual methods
};

extern "C" Animal* createAnimal();

#endif //STDLIB_ANIMAL_H
```

Now it runs.

Comment: Excellent workaround！It works like a charm，thank you so much！

Inspired by your solution, I think I should learn something in-depth about virtual method and late binding etc. 

Thank you again！

Comment: Can you then also remove the `--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files` from the commandline?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt No, you can't. If you do so, this command will fail

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt  Sorry, my comment above is **wrong**. I have just tried to remove `--unresolved-symbols=ignore-in-object-files`, and this command did still work .

Answer (score 0):

You have an *unresolved symbol* in your main executable. Do not ignore these error messages.

```
./tmp/cchZxfAz.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0x112): undefined reference to `Animal::shout[abi:cxx11]()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```